# Using websocket transport only in socket.io

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io, http-proxy

Basically, I wanted to proxy my REST requests and websocket request to the target server. So, what I was doing till now was using default transport in my client.
`["polling", "websocket"]` So that works all fine while using http-proxy. Firstly, the polling connection is established and then upgraded to websocket.

```
app.use('endpoint', function (req, res) {
    proxy.web(req, res, { target: { protocol: 'https', host: address.host, port: address.port } })
})

app.use('/socket.io', function (req, res) {
    proxy.web(req, res, { target: { host: address.host, port: address.port, path: '/socket.io' } })

})

server.on('upgrade', function (req, socket, head) {
    proxy.ws(req, socket, head, { target: { host: address.host, port: address.port, path: '/socket.io' } });
});
```

All set! I have setup a simple example for simplicity to work with websocket transport only to know how both are working differently. With the default transport options.
**Index.js**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
    <script src="https://localhost:5000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
]    <script>
      const socket = io.connect("https://localhost:5000",{auth: {
    token: "abc"
  }
});
      socket.on("connect", () => {
          console.log(socket.id);
      });
     </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Server.js**

```
const app = require('express')();
const fs=require('fs');
const credentials = { key: fs.readFileSync("localhost.key"), cert: fs.readFileSync("localhost.cert") };
const server = require('https').createServer(credentials, app);
const io = require('socket.io')(server, {
  cors: {
    origin: "*",
    methods: ["GET", "POST"]
  },
});
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html')
});
io.on("connection", (socket) => {
    console.log(socket.id);
    console.log(socket.handshake.auth)
  });
server.listen(5000,()=>{
    console.log("Server is listening at port 5000...");
})
```

Now in case of default transport, I am getting my request payload here
[image: Here I can see the auth in my request payload]But for websocket only, **my polling request keeps failing and websocket connection is not established.** I'm not using polling, thats understandable but why websocket connection is not established? Lets say if it does, can I get the auth token there? because when hadshake request comes, there is no payload and that's understandable because websocket doesn't work like HTTP.

Where to get the auth token in websocket handshake request, because initially handshake request is also an HTTP request after getting `Switching protocol 101` as a response. Because I need to switch purely to websocket transport instead of considering the HTTP long polling first. Then I need to access my token before proxying request to target server. The socket client and server is minimal possible example to test both behaviours not the actual one. I am successful in accessing this token via polling before proxying the request, now I need to disable polling and use websocket transport only. How an I going to access it then?